# reject numbers in a sequence of numbers that do not increase with same increase

Tags: r, increment, number-sequence

I have a sequence of numbers that I want to check and reject numbers that do not increase with similar level.

```
data <- c(1, 2, 5, 6, 6.25, 6.49, 6.75, 7.01, 8, 9, 11)
```

For example, for the data here I want to subset numbers with an increase of 0.25+/-0.1, and reject numbers that do not follow this rule. In this case, the subseted sequence would be (6, 6.25, 6.49, 6.75, 7.01).

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an ugly way to grab the indexes that you want to keep. Change `0.35` if you're interested in a different cutoff value

```
myfun <- function(D) {
            index <- unique(c(which(abs(diff(D)) < 0.35), which(abs(diff(D)) < 0.35)+1))
            return(sort(index))
        }
```

Call the function to obtain the answer you want with

```
data[myfun(data)]
# [1] 6.00 6.25 6.49 6.75 7.01
```

Another test

```
test <- c(1, 1.25, 2, 2.25, 3, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.45, 5.65)
test[myfun(test)]
# [1] 1.00 1.25 2.00 2.25 4.50 4.75 5.00 5.45
```

Comment: You can remove the `dplyr` dependency by replacing `which(dplyr::lag(abs(diff(D)) < 0.35, 1))` with `which(abs(diff(D)) < 0.35) + 1`. The `lag` essentially just adds one to the TRUE indices.

Comment: I did mention it was ugly